# sitefinity azure deployment cannot connect to database

Tags: azure, connection-string, azure-sql-database, sitefinity

I'm having trouble getting my new sitefinity deployment to windows azure hosting.  On the sitefinity project startup screen I can put in my azure connection string info and it bombs out saying the database type mismatches (mssql instead of azure).  I can't find where to change this so I'm unable to get the site to initialize.  Am I missing something?

Here is the error:

```
* There was an error trying to connect to the Database Server:
System.InvalidOperationException: Wrong database backend configuration detected: Connecting to 'Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 11.0.9117.67 Aug 4 2013 23:37:13 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation ' but configured for 'mssql'. at OpenAccessRuntime.Relational.sql.MsSqlDriver.customizeForServer(Connection con) at OpenAccessRuntime.Relational.sql.SqlDriver.InitializeFor(ConnectionString connectionString, Boolean noConnect, PropertySet props, DBDriver& driver, Connection& conn, ConnectionPoolType poolType) at OpenAccessRuntime.Relational.RelationalStorageManagerFactory..ctor(StorageManagerFactoryBuilder b) at OpenAccessRuntime.storagemanager.StorageManagerFactoryBuilder.createSmfForURL()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create your project directly on Azure - you should create it locally first.
Then, in the DataConfig.config file you will find the connection string. Make sure you change the dbType from MsSql to SqlAzure.

Also, in the web.config you need to uncomment this:

```
<!-- Begin telerik section  -->
 <!--<telerik>
   <sitefinity>
    <environment platform="WindowsAzure"/>
      <sitefinityConfig storageMode="Database" />
    </sitefinity>
 </telerik>-->
<!-- End telerik section  -->
```

I suggest you use Thunder to deploy your project to Azure:
http://www.sitefinity.com/documentation/documentationarticles/sitefinity-azure-configuration